# Does AD LDS support account lockout?

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

Does Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services support account lockout like how the full  Active Directory domain services does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, AD LDS supports and enforces the password policy settings
>   and account lockout settings that are provided by Windows Server 2008,
>   including the following:
>
> Minimum age
>
> Maximum age
>
> Complexity
>
> History
>
> Too many failed logon attempts
>
> Disabling and enabling of accounts
>
> If the server on which AD LDS is running belongs to a workgroup, the
>   server's local password policy settings and account lockout settings
>   are implemented. If the server on which AD LDS is running belongs to a
>   domain, the password policy settings and account lockout settings from
>   Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) are implemented

.

From this site - [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731012(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731012%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: And if you set a policy to be applied locally on a domain machine, it will take over. No need to lower the domain wide policy to accomodate AD-LDS users (which might have other needs).